# Angular6 : ERROR: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: i is not a constructor

Tags: angular, angular6

Getting error when I used the below command

```
ng build --prod --aot
```

My `package.json`

```
{
 "name": "xyz",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "xyz ",
 "author": "xyz",
 "homepage": "https://xyz.co",
 "copyright": " xyz",
 "scripts": {
   "ng": "ng",
   "start": "ng serve",
   "build": "ng build --prod",
   "test": "ng test",
   "lint": "ng lint",
   "e2e": "ng e2e"
 },
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "^0.803.21",
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.0-rc.12",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/material": "^6.0.0-rc.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
    "@coreui/angular": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "^1.2.0",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars": "^16.4.55",
    "@yellowspot/ng-truncate": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-2-daterangepicker": "^1.1.52",
    "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.8.1",
    "angular-gauge-chart": "^0.6.0",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.6.0",
    "angular2-infinite-scroll": "^0.3.5",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^4.1.1",
    "angular4-datepicker": "^1.0.1",
    "angular4-multiselect-dropdown": "^2.0.0",
    "c3": "^0.6.6",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "core-js": "2.5.5",
    "cronstrue": "^1.31.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "http-status-codes": "^1.3.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "2.22.1",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "ng-circle-progress": "^1.0.0",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.3",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-daterangepicker": "^2.0.12",
    "ng2-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-gauge-with-color-band": "^0.1.2",
    "ng2-ion-range-slider": "^2.0.0",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.4.7",
    "ng2-timezone-selector": "^0.2.4",
    "ng4-loading-spinner": "^1.1.3",
    "ng6-toastr-notifications": "^1.0.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "2.0.4",
    "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "^1.1.1",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^6.0.1",
    "ngx-mat-daterange-picker": "0.0.2",
    "ngx-multiselect": "^1.1.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.1.1",
    "ngx-password-toggle": "^1.0.3",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "5.3.5",
    "ngx-read-more": "^1.0.0",
    "ngx-select-dropdown": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-toggle-switch": "^2.0.5",
    "ngx-treeview": "^6.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "rxjs": "6.0.0-uncanny-rc.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-uncanny-rc.7",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
    "sockjs": "^0.3.19",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.22.0",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "view-more-less": "^1.0.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
    },
 "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.4",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0"
   },
  "engines": {
     "node": ">= 8.9.4",
     "npm": ">= 5.6.0"
   }
 }
```

[image]

I tested it locally and it **compiled successfully**

But in git,

I used the same command while deploying angular App using jenkins , build was successful but showing error like below in browser.
[image]

For testing purpose, I used the command like `ng build --prod` (without aot compilation) its working both locally and in browser.

Is there any way to check the error??

**The problem which I understood is:**

--aot (aot compilation) showing some error.

**Doubt:-**

Locally --aot is compiling successfully. But in browser showing the above error.Why??

Can anybody help me to find the problem??

Comment: have you updated your angular cli version recently?

Comment: No.."@angular/cli": "^6.0.0-rc.5", this is my angular cli version

Comment: refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53641895/11048793

Comment: --aot=false, what it means.. I dont want to solve the problem temporarily.

Comment: can anybody help??'

Comment: still not able to solve this problem??

Comment: try deleting node_modules and install them again